# Как считывать нажатия на кнопки мыши?

Tags: c++

Нужно считывать нажатия на кнопку мыши с помощью с++. Слышал, что это можно сделать через хуки(hook), но что это и как этим пользоваться, я понятия не имею. Подскажите пожалуйста какую нибудь функцию или библиотеку.

Comment: нажатия в окне программы или вообще любые, в т.ч. за её пределами?

Comment: @VladislavTikhomirov, любые.

Comment: посмотрите в сторону directinput

Comment: @Zhihar, а можно поподробнее?

Comment: Все, нашёл,  я использую GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LBUTTON)